# Use find on a model inside a static

Tags: node.js, static, find, mongoose

What I try to do is something like this:

```
A_Schema.statics.init = function init() {
    A_Schema.find({}, {}, {
    }, function (error, docs) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('There is no error.');
        }
        else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};
```

I mean, using the find method of the `A_Schema` model but it keeps crashing.

I suppose that is because the inner `A_Schema` is must be a properly defined Model and not a Schema, but I don't know how to do it.

I already tried:

```
A_Schema.statics.init = function init() {
    mongoose.model('A_Schema', A_Schema).find({}, {}, {
    }, function (error, docs) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('There is no error.');
        }
        else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};
```

and

```
A_Schema.statics.init = function init() {
    mongoose.model('A_Schema').find({}, {}, {
    }, function (error, docs) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('There is no error.');
        }
        else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};
```

but it keep crashing.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Diosney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it seems that I overlook the `mongoose` documentation.

At [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) can be see the example:

```
animalSchema.statics.findByName = function (name, cb) {
  this.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') }, cb);
}
```

So, inside a static the `this` reference must be used instead of the named model.